# IBM MFP cli install failure: npm install -g mfpdev-cli

Tags: mobile, npm

When I attempt to install the IBM Mobile First CLI (mfpdev-cli), I'm getting an error.

Command:

```
npm install -g mfpdev-cli
```

Error details:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/timothy/dev/project/mdo-windows-support/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
...
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

It looks like it's trying to create an npm named 'mdo-windows-support' locally, but it fails. Any suggestions?

npm version: 5.0.1

node version: v8.0.0

Comment: still error for me, node 8.x

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that the versions of npm/node were the culprit. I switched back to the LTS version of Node, and it worked.